# What is the meaning of "to swing the election"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I know that a swing voter is someone who has not yet decided who to vote for in an election. But I'm not sure what the meaning of "to swing the election" is in the following two contexts. Does "swing" mean "to make a certain candidate win" the election?

> Pennsylvania: With 20 electoral votes, this state appears most likely
> **to swing the election** next week.

> Mr Ryan allowed that there was likely "organised shenanigans" in elections, but said that any incidents were in no way broad enough  **to swing the election** in Mr Biden's
> favour.

Comment: *"I know that a swing voter is someone who has not yet decided who to vote for in an election."* - No, a swing voter is somebody who doesn't always vote for the same party in every election.

Comment: @nnnnnn, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swing-voter

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Swing+voter and https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/swing-voter?q=Swing+voter and  https://www.lexico.com/definition/swing_voter  all back up my definition. (One of those also allows your definition.) Somebody who had not yet made up their mind who to vote for obviously does not vote for the same party every time, but also they don't stop being a swing voter the moment they do make up their mind for the current election because they may still vote differently next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/swing) has in its 4th meaning:

> **swing**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **4.1** Have a decisive influence on (something, especially a vote or election)
> *an attempt to swing the vote in their favour*

In the first example: with 20 electoral [college] votes, the result from Pennsylvania will probably decide the outcome of the [presidential] election.

In the second example: it is unlikely that any attempt to 'fix' the voting will influence the final result.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, to "swing an election" means to decide its outcome one way or the other.

Comment: More specifically, it means to change the result from what it would other be, as shown in the examples (e.g. the vote is A 49%, B 51%) but some place/group tips the balance so A wins, then that place/group swings the vote.